# Can the exit code of a process overflow for small values?

Tags: c++, bash, cmd, terminal, exit-code

I am writing a testing framework and in main() I return the number of failed tests. For example:

```
int main() {
    int failedTests = runTests();
    return failedTests;
}
```

So can this "int" overflow? Can I get `%ERROR_LEVEL%` to be `== 0` when I actually returned something different than 0? Does it depend on the host operating system? What are the usual maximum values? Can I be sure that an integer < 32768 (2^16 - a short) will always fit?

**EDIT:**

I've had problems with python `sys.exit` which uses the 0-127 range (almost) always so I am careful now

Comment: `%ERROR_LEVEL%` doesn't that apply for a windows `cmd` shell? For `bash` you use `$?` IIRC.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes - my question is for all platforms - any information is useful

Comment: If you want to get the last return value of program in bash, or similar, you use `$?`, that is correct.

Comment: There are three portable return values: 0, `EXIT_SUCCESS`, and `EXIT_FAILURE`. The latter two are defined in <stdlib.h> and in <cstdlib>. Beyond that, you're into system-specific behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends upon the operating system. On Linux, it is restricted to 8 bits, so can be 0 (for success) or any positive integer not greater than 255. See [_exit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/_exit.2.html) & [wait(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html).

Only two values are standardized (by name): `EXIT_SUCCESS` (usually it is 0) and `EXIT_FAILURE` (often as 1). Notice that the standard defines the name (and probably also the behavior of `exit(0);`...) but not their value.

You could write the number (of failed tests) to `stdout`  or to some file specified thru some program argument.

FreeBSD has defined in its [sysexits(3)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysexits&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%204.3-RELEASE&format=html) a set of exit names and codes, but they are not standardized, e.g. in POSIX. See [POSIX documentation on exit](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exit.html).

Comment: **WRONG!** Neither `EXIT_SUCCESS` nor `EXIT_FAILURE` have any values attached. Their values are implementation defined. While `0` will indicate successful program execution, it's not required that `EXIT_SUCCESS` also equals `0`.

Comment: @Leandros - they're not implementation defined. They're simply defined by the implementation. "Implementation-defined" has a particular meaning in the standard: when some behavior is implementation defined the implementation has to tell you what it does.

Comment: @Leandros - no. `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` already have defined behavior: the standard says what they do. There is no obligation on the implementation to say what those names do. The **values** may well be implementation-specific, but the **effects** of using those names are **not** implementation defined.

Comment: @Leandros - the **values** are **not** implementation defined. Different implementations might use different values, but that is **not** what implementation-defined means.

Comment: @Leandros - I was project editor for the C++ standard for eight years, so I think I know my way around it fairly well.

Comment: @Leandros - please cite the paragraph in the C++ standard or the C standard that says that the **values** of the macros `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are implementation defined. Hint: you won't find one.

Comment: Note: On Linux, the exit(3) exit function is specified as `void exit(int status);` with the documentation stating "The exit() function causes normal process termination and the value of status & 0377 is returned to the parent" - so you don't get to use the full range of `int`.

Comment: @Leandros -  that's what I said in the beginning: the values are implementation-specific but they are not implementation defined, because implementation defined has a particular meaning in the standard that does not apply here.

Comment: @Leandros - because people are often confused about the meaning of "implementation defined", as you've quite thoroughly demonstrated.

Comment: @PeteBecker To settle this once and for all, yes, you're absolutely correct and I was misguided by the standard, I actually thought it would qualify as implementation defined. I absolutely know what implementation defined means, I just thought both status would qualify as such. I apologize if I was rude or inappropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can overflow just like any other `int`.

The standard describes `int` to be at least 16 bits wide. Returning anything which does not fit into an `int` is undefined behaviour.

What the environment, in which the C++ program runs, does with the value, is implementation defined and not described by the standard.

Three values are mentioned by the C++ standard: `EXIT_SUCCESS`, `EXIT_FAILURE` and `0`. Both `0` and `EXIT_SUCCESS` indicate successful program execution, while the other defines failure. `EXIT_SUCCES` is not required to be zero.

Quoting the C++11 standard:

> If status is zero or EXIT_SUCCESS, an
>                   implementation-defined form of the status successful termination is returned. If status is EXIT_-
>                   FAILURE, an implementation-defined form of the status unsuccessful termination is returned.
>                   Otherwise the status returned is implementation-defined.225

The usual values supported varies by implementation to implementation, Windows uses full 32 bit integers as return values, and the full 32 bits can be obtained through various means. POSIX only specifies how the 8 low order bits can be obtained, and thus shells often truncate the values returned.